# Single instance of a service in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

First of all I know this answer was posted a lot of times before, but I just cannot make mine work and may be somebody here can help.

I am using angular-cli beta 5 to generate a new project.
I use angular 2 rc1.

I have a class named ApplicationConfiguration <- this one I want to make one instance of, trough out each component of my application.

In my main.ts I have:

```
bootstrap(MyProjWebAppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ApplicationConfiguration, provide(Http, {
  useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions, router: Router, appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration) => new HttpServiceLayer(xhrBackend, requestOptions, router, appConfig),
  deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, ApplicationConfiguration]
})]);
```

My ApplicationConfiguration class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationConfiguration {

  constructor() {
    console.log('aaa');
  }
}
```

And an example component of how I inject my ApplicationConfiguration:

```
import { ApplicationConfiguration } from '../..//services/application-configuration/application-configuration';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-log-in',
  templateUrl: 'log-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['log-in.component.css'],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ApplicationConfiguration, LogInService]
})
export class LogInComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private _service: LogInService, private appConfig: ApplicationConfiguration, private _router: Router) { }
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong, but every time I navigate to a new page and I inject my class, I can see that a new instance is being created

If you need any other info please let me know.

A solution for this problem is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not provide the class multiple times if you want only one instance. Angular DI maintains one instance per provider.

Therefore remove `ApplicationConfiguration` from `LogInComponent` to

```ts
 providers: [LogInService]
```

I don't see why a factory would be necessary for your custom `HttpServiceLayer`. This should do the same:

**update (>= RC.5)**

```ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyProjWebAppComponent], 
  bootstrap: [MyProjWebAppComponent], 
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule, HttpModule], 
  providers: [
   ApplicationConfiguration, 
   {provide Http: useClass: HttpServiceLayer})
  ]
});
```

**original**
    bootstrap(MyProjWebAppComponent, [
      ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
      HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
      ApplicationConfiguration, 
      provide(Http, {useClass: HttpServiceLayer})
    ]);

Comment: Hi again Günter Zöchbauer :) . Off course I have tried your solution, this is the solution I see everywhere on the internet, the problem is, if I remove ApplicationConfiguration from LogIn's providers, I get the error: 'EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for ApplicationConfiguration!' Also, so we can rule out that my bootstrap-ing is wrong, I use the one that you have provided and I still get the same error

Comment: I don't think changing the providers is helping here. The error is caused by something else. Probably something wrong with the imports. This one `'../..//services/...` looks a bit weird (`//`). Can you please check them again?

Comment: Your services do all have the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Comment: OMG!! It was the // problem. I did not see this one. Thnx again for the help! But I find it very strange that it worked if I was adding it in the providers.. I don't know what was happening, but I am glad it is resolved know.

Comment: Glad to hear. No idea either :D

Comment: Weird. I did the same mistake and was totally confused for the past 4 hours! :-D